# Change Factor to Time for FFDF Object in R

Tags: r, time

I have a `ffdf` objects named `A` with `(dim=c(26416266,25))`. I'm trying to convert the Time variable `(D_Time)` from type `Factor` to `Time`, so that I can perform `summary()` and get the `min, max, average and median` for `D_Time`.

Example of `D_Time` are as follow:

```
> D_Time
1     07:40
2     08:01
3     02:24
4     08:15
5     01:45
6     04:56
7     02:12
8     07:35
9     05:48
10    11:50
```

I have try to change `A` to `dataframe` and convert it using `chron` but my memory is running out. I try to use `chron`, `POSIXlt` but keep getting error message. I also try to paste `:00` as `ss` to make the format `hh:mm:ss` but still no luck.

I'm wonder, is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with type `Time`. I don't think this exists in base R. POSIXct exists though. You should use that as in `as.POSIXct(paste("2013-01-01", "08:00:00", sep=" "))`. For ffdf objects use `myffdf$dt <- with(myffdf, as.POSIXct(mydate, mytime, sep=" "), by = 250000)`

Comment: I have tried it, but keep getting error messages `Error in as.POSIXct.default(A$D_Date, A$D_Time, sep = " ") : 
  do not know how to convert 'A$D_Date' to class “POSIXct”`. Both are in `Factor` class with `VirtualVmode=integer`

Comment: Use with. As in `A$dt <- with(A, as.POSIXct(paste(D_Date, D_Time, sep=" "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), by = 250000)`

Comment: Maybe you can post your answer and approve it as being solved, so that other people can also benefit from what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @jwijffels for this solution:

```
A$D_DateTime <- with(A, as.POSIXct(paste(D_Date, D_Time, sep=" "), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), by = 250000)
```