# Format Integer as Fixed Width for FFDF Object in R

Tags: r, format, bigdata, printf

I'm trying to fixed the format for `integer` type variable `(F_Number)` in `FFDF` object named `A` with `(dim=c(20000000,28))`.

Example of `F_Number` are as follow:

```
> F_Number
1     1089
2     9
3     4057
4     25
5     108
6     109
7     0
8     9089
9     117
10    118
```

I'd like to have the same width of all values and having 4 digits like this:

```
> F_Number
1     1089
2     0009
3     4057
4     0025
5     0108
6     0109
7     0000
8     9089
9     0117
10    0118
```

I have tried using `formatC(A$F_Number, width=4, format="d", flag="0")` and `sprintf("%04d",A$F_Number)`

but keep getting an error message: `Warning message:
In formatC(A$F_Number, width = 4, format = "d", flag = "0") :
  class of 'x' was discarded` when using `formatC` and `character(0)` when using `sprintf`

How to handle that?

Comment: Use `with` as in your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849855/change-factor-to-time-for-ffdf-object-in-r. So with(A, formatC(F_Number, ...))

Comment: As always @jwijffels, you're awesome! Thanks.